# Web Scraping na página InfoMoney

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho o código abaixo que acessa a página da INfoMoney e seleciona a opção Todos do botão para retornar todos os resultados.
O problema é que só seleciona, mas não clica para retornar todas as cotações.

```
Sub GetHtmlDocument()
    Dim IE              As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc         As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLOptions     As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLOption      As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.infomoney.com.br/ibovespa"
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
    Set HTMLOptions = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("option") 'É um botão
    For Each HTMLOption In HTMLOptions
        If HTMLOption.innerText = "Todos" Then
            HTMLOption.Selected = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next HTMLOption
End Sub
```

Comment: Paulo, pode dizer qual o link no site que você deseja clicar?

Comment: Bom dia! Na página especificada no código, é o botão (ou ComboBox) com o nome "ver 10 itens", da Carteira IBOVESPA. Consegui alterar para "Todos". Só não consigo clicar em "Todos" para retornar todos os ativos.